# Why the $q^{\text{th}}$ homology group of $\mathbb R$ is the trivial group?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

It is well know that if $q=0$, then $H_q(\mathbb R)$ must be the integers (since $\mathbb R$ is path connected). In general, why is $H_q(\mathbb R)$ the trivial group for $q\geq 2$?

Comment: $\Bbb R$ is contractible, so $H_q(\Bbb R) = H_q(\{0\}) = 0$ for $q \geq 1$.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{R}$ is contractible (i.e. homotopy equivalent to a point) and homology is a homotopy invariant, so

$$H_q(\mathbb{R}; \mathbb{Z}) \cong H_q(\{0\}; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \begin{cases} \mathbb{Z} &\ \text{if}\ q = 0\\
0 &\ \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$

Note, $H_q(\mathbb{R}; \mathbb{Z}) = 0$ for $q = 1$ too.